# How can i dump a FAT32 file system in a USB in windows / Linux platform?

Tags: windows, linux, filesystems, usb, fat32

I have one USB stick having FAT32 type file system.I really in need to dump and analyze that file system in the usb stick in windows or in linux platform.

My ultimate aim is to read the usb's hardware( ,type and manufacturer) information by reading that dump file.

Comment: Why do you expect to find the device type and manufacturer embedded within the filesystem?

Comment: Exactly. As the name suggests, the file system holds information about the files, not the device. You must interrogate the device itself or ask the OS what it know about the device for that kind of info.

Comment: because , I bought one 2 GB usb stick, when i plugged the stick in tothe machine it is showing the size as 2GB ..But actually the total size is 400MB(i can only store upto 400 MB)...so i need to see where the manufacturer has embedded the details of the usb stick(that is of course in the file system right?) , so that OS will read that from there..

Comment: Chances are, that 2 GB stick you bought with only a 400 MB capacity had another partition created by the manufacturer to hold "tools" or "utilities" or just crap that you don't need. Try repartitioning the drive to one single 2 GB partition, and you should realize its full storage. Otherwise, the package was mismarked and the manufacturer lied at you. The OS reads the size from the file system, but this guaranteed to be correct. It has nothing to do with any information embedded by the manufacturer.

Comment: How can i view that file system as dump file ?

Comment: @Admin: If this is off topic then please move this to other related forum rather than closing the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will not find the information you are looking for in the file system, those are embedded in the chip and are transmitted when the device gets plugged in. You will find all details in the device manager if you look up the details of the device.

Regarding your comment: It is irrelevant for the OS what the actual filesystem is, as the controller on the device controls the access to the actual flash memory. If the controller says that there are only 400mb to be accessed, you can only access 400mb. You either got a faulty stick or it's a fraud, you probably should check with the origin of it (ie. where you bought it). Sometimes, you can flash the device's firmware, for that the information you get in the device manager is enough. However, at most times, you are out of luck - return the stick if you can in that case.

Comment: Then , I need to get the details of the usb stick from the usb controller.but HOW?

Comment: as I said - details page in the device manager. locate the device, go to "properties" -> "details" tab. The respective property should be selected in the window already, if not, look for "device instance identification" (or similar, I have german windows). The identification looks like this: VEN_XXXX&DEV_XXXX&... (X = digit). With that, you can identify the device. If there are only 0's, you are out of luck.

Comment: How can i manually read this informations directly from the usb controller ?

Comment: Manually? You could use the win32 api to get the information via the internal usb driver. However, I don't see the point in that, just get it from the device manager and look it up?

Answer (score -1):

there seem to be more and more questions that are answered by "why do you want to do that" instead of real information. Strange.

Here is an answer:

Don't use Windows. Use Linux, plug in the stick, and use 'dd' to dump partitions from the stick to files.

Cheers.

Comment: No information on the USB device id , manufacturer etc will be on there. you could look at pyusb in order to get the info programatically. its basicall a wrapper around libusb